# Linux change to another /dev/ttyX and run program there

Tags: linux, sh, tty

Is it possible to run a script on /dev/tty1 and spawn a program to run on /dev/tty2 and wait for it to complete and run the other commands in the script? For instance:

```
echo "Hello, this is from terminal 1"
chvt 2
sh myprogram.sh (I want it to run on tty2, but it runs on tty1)
chvt 1
```

**myprogram.sh:**

```
echo "Hello' this is from terminal 2, please type your input:"
read A
exit A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `openvt`.

```
openvt -c 2 sh myprogram.sh
```

Comment: I get: `Couldnt get a file descriptor referring to the console
Could not get a file descriptor referring to the console'